# Accidently added linux swap partition to windows without formatting

Tags: swap, partitioning

The PC no longer had Ubuntu, I had already added the Ubuntu storage partition to windows but forgot to add the swap partition. Some days later I added the swap partition to windows through windows by deallocating and then resizing the main partition. Would there be a problem considering the windows partition was NTFS and swap partition was linux-swap? Do you have to make the partitions of the same format before you can add them?

Comment: ps. Regretting removing ubuntu, stuck with windows in automatic repair loop

Comment: no should be no problem, resizing includes the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you grow a partition it will always extend its own filesystem to the added space.